# Google's S2 library - any alternatives?

Tags: geometry, google, geohash

Is there any alternative to Google's S2 geometry library? It looks it was updated 4 years back and hardly any documentation.

I need a library to divide cities into zones of the area I need. S2 looks good solution, but its documentation is very poor. I have even no clue how to use it. I am looking at its Java library which will be compatible with the project I am doing.

If no alternative, any pointers how to start on S2? Like, how do I create cells with IDs of the resolution I need? How do I use them to search for the proximity given a point??

Comment: Would look at D3.js https://www.jasondavies.com/maps/rotate/ S2 is deprecated by google.

Comment: @Mapperz Although there is no active development on S2 by, the library is far from dead. MongoDB (database), Foursquare are few larger companies that confirmed to use S2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have recently written [a tutorial about the S2](http://blog.christianperone.com/?p=2840) and I think that the S2 is what you really need. I have made the same you need in the tutorial so I won't repeat the code here.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will go through this and get back to you on your blog.